# Inserting a declared variable (var) in window.open.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm just studying about the javascript and asp.net.
I want to insert/append a declared var in window.location.href, I have this code and its working just as I wanted to.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    //var siteURL = document.getElementByID("txtURL");
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

This function is called/triggered through an 'onclick' event. But When I change the code to:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var siteURL = document.getElementByID("txtURL");
    window.location.href = siteURL;
}
</script>
```

Can someone help me make the second code given work just like the first one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no `document.getElementByID` function. It's `document.getElementById` (last char differs).

This function will return object so to get it's value you should use `innerHTML` (or `value` if it's input field) attribute like this `var siteURL = document.getElementByID("txtURL").innerHTML;` and then pass this variable to `window.location.href`.

Comment: seems like you are the only one to catch it +1

Comment: @A.Wolff To catch what?

Comment: @VisioN `getElementByID` but didn't saw your answer before posting comment, my apologies :(

Comment: @A.Wolff [Paul S.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20071630/1249581) has also caught it first of everyone here.

Comment: @VisioN ya, i have something sticking in my eyes, sorry

Comment: @A.Wolff No apologies, that happens to all ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problems lay with `getElementByID`. Firstly, you've made a typo, the last letter should be lower case `getElementById`, and secondly, this returns a *Node*, from which you probably want it's *value*

```
var siteURL = document.getElementById("txtURL").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, JavaScript is case sensitive language, so the correct method name for selecting an *element* by ID is `document.getElementById()`.

Next, if element with ID `"txtURL"` is a form field, e.g. `<input>` or `<select>` you should get its value with `siteURL.value`. Otherwise if it is any other text container, e.g. `<div>` or `<span>` with URL as its text, you may use `siteURL.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var siteURL = document.getElementById("txtURL"); 
//siteURL is just a reference to the text field, not it's value
```

your variable `siteURL` is just a dom object at this stage, you need to call the `.value` property to grab it's value to use as a href. and JavaScript is case sensitive so it's `.getElementById()` not `.getElementByID()`. The code below should work just fine

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var siteURL = document.getElementById("txtURL").value; //add .value here
    window.location.href = siteURL;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` returns a DOM object, not a string.

If you have your url stored in a node which ID is "txtURL", you have to access the information itself, probably if stored as contents of the node: via .innerHTML or via .html() in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByID("txtURL")` returns a DOM Node. `window.location.href` is a `String`-like object. Giving it a DOM Node is silly.

If `#txtURL` is an `input`, you can do:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById("txtURL").value;
```

If it's a TextNode you can do something like:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById("txtURL").nodeValue;
```

but this is getting iffy.